# How to get the CSS3 background image to appear?

Tags: html, css

`background-image: url(img/hero.jpg)` is not showing on my website. I tried `../img/hero.jpg` but no luck. Any solutions? I tried a pdf image as well.

Comment: Have you looked in your browser's dev tools inspector to see if there is an error?

Comment: GET file:///Users/aminrashid431/Desktop/burmese/vendors/css/normalize.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND so the css3 aspect of this website is the error. that's how its filed. it should work

Comment: Silly question maybe, but just to check, when you say 'my website' in the question I had assumed it was a website that was on a server, published somewhere. But are you saying you are trying it out on your local machine? If so where are the other parts of the website filed?

Comment: it must not be a website but its in the devolopment process. what would you call that?

Answer (score 0):

Open element with background-image with dev tools

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

**or:**

- `right click`->`Inspect`

and look if there is good URL: [image: i.stack.imgur.com/okn3v.png]
Click on the circled link. If image not appears, there is your error.